# Repeat a line of code without writing it again

Tags: python, list, random, formatting, numbers

```
      import random
     a = [[random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)],
         [random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)]]

     for i in a:
    for c in i:
        print(c, end = " ")
    print()
```

that is just a part if my programm. I need 10x10 random generated numbers. Is there a way to write/formate it better. Maybe in less lines.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For one, you know to use list comprehension to do `[random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(0, 10)]`, don't you see how you can do the same to simplify your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a double list comprehension:

```
a = [[random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(0, 10)] for _ in range(0, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use another loop outside the one building the inner loops:

```
a = [[random.randint(1, 1000) for i in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
```

Or use `random.choices` to save on using the inner loop:

```
a = [random.choices(range(1, 1001), k=10) for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should fulfill your requirements

```
for i in range(10):
    print([random.randint(1, 1000) for j in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I already hinted at double list comprehension in my comment, but anyway:

```
import random
a = [random.choices(range(1, 1001), k=10) for _ in range(10)] # range will not include 1000, while randint will, so it has to be range(1001)
```

If you want unique elements (per sublist), you can use `random.sample()` instead of `random.choices()`

Comment: Tried `sample`, [got 314 twice](https://tio.run/##PY3BCgIhGITv@xQDXRQklC5d9kkiwlrLn1x/UWPp6c12o9sM881MelfP8XBMuTWaE@eKbOPE82Ax4rTpfbFzCk5093DCKBitjVR4jkZL3DnjAor4xVqesdsMFgoBkWuPb@E1uW9TKyyegluPKNYVUigMqvC2oDKu7r/Wn4aUOyesbO0D).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, You've got it twice, but in different sublists - i.e. as a result of different calls of `random.sample()`. If you want unique 100 numbers split in 10 sublists the approach would be different - draw 100 unique numbers with `random.sample`, then just split these 100 numbers in 10 sublists.